# What is the difference between nodes, cluster, and database in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Reading thru the documentation of aws, im quite confused with these three concepts

```
Cluster: composed of one or more compute nodes; composed of one or mode database 

Compute node: run the query execution plans and transmit data among themselves to serve these queries

Database: User data is stored on the compute nodes
```

With this it is easy to assume that a compute node and a database is the same, isn't it? But when creating a redshift cluster, a portion of it is named as database configuration but seemingly referring to cluster. Below is an image of it, if my understanding is correct from the documentation, database configuration should be referring to compute nodes and not the cluster.

[image: Redshift Cluter Creation]

With these, what exactly is a cluster, database, and a compute node?

Comment: Any link to that documentation?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_high_level_system_architecture.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/concepts-diagrams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With this it is easy to assume that a compute node and a database is the same, isn't it?

No, that's not the case. You can have single-node Redshift cluster with multiple databases, or a single (large) database hosted on multiple compute nodes.

Basically, node refers to the hardware layer of Redshift, while database refers to software layer only.

Your screenshot shows only a default database called `dev`. You can create many more if you want. All hosted on the same cluster.